# Is there a way to add vector image to background on ipad application?

Tags: ios, ipad

I am simply trying to add an image to background which will not be disrupted with zooming?
Is there way to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Each individual view added to an iOS interface can respond differently to touch events, including not responding at all. Just add an UIImageView behind the rest of your content in Interface Builder, and don't implement any user interaction for that view. Here's how to construct an example:

Start with [Apple's sample code Touches](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/Touches/Introduction/Intro.html). Open the `MainWindow.xib`. Add an `Image View` to `My View`. Move it behind all the other items in `My View`. Set the image to an available image, say `CyanSquare.png`. The mode of the `Image View` should default to `Scale To Fill`, and `User Interaction Enabled` to off, but change the settings if they are not so. Run the app to see that the background image will not be disrupted as you interact with the squares including zooming the squares.